# Show formated value into chart column

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, mschart

Well, I'm getting the values from my chart from a function that return a dataTable with a date and a decimal column, my issue happens when I try to convert the decimal column to the currency for easier reading, on the axis it works fine, althought it is not working in the top of the columns.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
Chart.DataSource = tabelaVendas
Chart.DataBind()

Chart.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column

Chart.Series(0).XValueMember = "Mês"
Chart.Series(0).YValueMembers = "Valor"

//Then show it as my local currency
Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "C2"
```

And an example:

[Example chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbFJO.jpg)

How can I set the values at the top of the column as currency? I couldn't find any info about it, I understood that once you convert the axis it should convert the top of the column, maybe I'm doing the formatting wrong.

Comment: Set the Series  Labels: `yourSeries.Label = "#VALY{C2}";`

Comment: @TaW that did it! If you could post it as the answer I would mark it as correct, and if you don't mind, where could I find documentation about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Taw comment did the trick, all I had to do was:

```
chart.series(0).label = "#VALY{C2}"
```

For those wondering what VALY means, it's just the default string for winforms chart label of the Y axis, there's also VALX, for the X axis.

Althought I couldn't find any official docummentation about it, if you do, please comment below!

Comment: Please see the "Keyword Reference" section in the following link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687.aspx